# Buttons not working after publishing unity game to play store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, google-play

I just published my first unity game and I downloaded on my phone and when tried pressing the play button it doesn't start! it actually registers touch and I know that because of the color of button changes when pressed but the actual function of the button doesn't work. It works fine in the editor.

EDIT: here's the button function screenshot:[image]

Edit2: here is the code of the button function:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayBtnScript : MonoBehaviour {

public AudioSource clickSound;


string[] scenes = { "PlayScene", "PlayScene2", "PlayScene3", "PlayScene4", "PlayScene5", "PlayScene6",
    "PlayScene7" };
public void StartGameBtn()
{



    string name = scenes[Random.Range(0, scenes.Length - 1)];

    clickSound.Play();
    Initiate.Fade( name, Color.black, 2.0f);
   
  //  SceneManager.LoadScene("StartMenu");
   
   
}
```

}

Initiate.Fade is just an asset from the asset store that makes it easier to fade between scenes so the first parameter is the scene to go to and 2nd is color of the fade.
"name" is a variable that just generates a random scene so then i put it in the Initiate.Fade so that it loads a random scene.

Here is the link to the asset:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/simple-fade-scene-transition-system-81753

Comment: Could you show your code of what happens / is supposed to happen when pressing the button

Comment: Yes i will put that right no but the button works in the editor and even on unity remote but when i build it, it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: Can you please include the **code** that is executed by this button?

Comment: Yes i'll do that  now.

Comment: Please don't post images of code .. rather copy & paste the code and format it as code using the `{ }` button. Also include all necessary details .. e.g. what is `Initiate.Fade` doing? Also note that `Random.Range` is **excluding** the max value .. you rather would want `Random.Range(0, scenes.Length)`!

Comment: Okay im sorry ill update it

Comment: Please note that it is really difficult to help you if we don't see the code or at least a link to according asset .. it sounds like the stuff in `Initiate.Fade` is kind of essential for your method and the thing that isn't working as expected so we would need to see what it does in order to properly comment on this issue

Comment: here is the link to the asset that i talked about: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/simple-fade-scene-transition-system-81753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is the problem, that appears when you click button or before that. To see possible error you have to:

- Enable USB debugging in your phone
- Connect phone to computer
- Debug errors in windows cmd or terminal

(See the picture) https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWuxZ.png

If %JAVA_ROOT% in your windows environment isn't assigned, instead of %JAVA_ROOT% paste your android sdk location.

Works with android games and window os.